# Work with relationships in python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am completely junior programming in python, and I want to see if anyone can guide me with this problem I have encountered.

I'm trying to make a REST API for a store, and I'm stuck with relationships. The problem I have is that I have the following endpoint, models, services and every time I try to make a post to the API I get these errors

```
AttributeError: "n" is not a valid field for <Specification(id='1', name='Polyester', date_added='2017-04-11 12:39:31.871208')>.
WARNING:root:(sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: specification.name [SQL: 'INSERT INTO specification (name, date_added) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('Polyester', '2017-04-11 12:39:31.871208')]
```

My product Model:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

specification = db.Table('product_specification', db.metadata,
                         db.Column('specification_id', db.Integer,
                                   db.ForeignKey('specification.id')),
                         db.Column('product_id', db.Integer,
                                   db.ForeignKey('product.id'))
                         )


class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'product'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    brand = db.Column(db.String(180), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    specification = db.relationship('Specification', secondary=specification,
                                    lazy='joined', backref=db.backref('product', lazy='dynamic'))

    @staticmethod
    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(
            brand=self.brand,
            description=self.description,
            price=self.price,
            date_added=self.date_added,
            specification=self.specification
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Products(id='%s', brand='%s', description='%s'," \
               "price='%s', date_created='%s'>" % (
                   self.id,
                   self.brand,
                   self.description,
                   self.price,
                   self.date_added,
                   self.specification
               )


class ProductSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True),
    brand = fields.String(),
    description = fields.String(),
    price = fields.Float(),
    date_added = fields.DateTime()
    specification = fields.Nested(SpecificationsSchema)

    class Meta:
        type_ = 'product'
        model = Product,
        fields = (
            'id', 'brand', 'description', 'price', 'date_added', 'specification'
        )
```

My specification Model:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Specification(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'specification'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    date_added = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())

    @staticmethod
    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(
            name=self.name,
        )

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Specification(id='%s', name='%s', date_added='%s')>" % (
            self.id,
            self.name,
            self.date_added,
        )


class SpecificationsSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer(dump_only=True)
    name = fields.String()
    date_added = fields.DateTime()


    class Meta:
        type_ = 'specification'
        model = Specification
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'date_added')
```

My services:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def add_product(
    brand=None,
    description=None,
    price=None,
    specification=None
):

    try:
        products = Product(
            brand=brand,
            description=description,
            price=price,
            specification=specification
        )

        # Add product object to the db session
        db.session.add(products)
        # commit product object to the db session
        db.session.commit()
        # return product object status
        return products

    except IntegrityError as why:
        # Logging the error.
        logging.warning(why)
        # Return none if there is product unique constraint error.
        return None

    except Exception as why:
        # Logging the error.
        logging.warning(why)
        # Return error.
        return None
```

My view

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


@api.route('/create/product', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(allow_header=['Content-Type'])
def create_products():
    try:
        # Get product data
        json_dict = request.get_json()
        brand = json_dict['brand']
        description = json_dict['description']
        price = json_dict['price']
        specification = json_dict['specification']

    except Exception as why:
        # Logging the error.
        logging.warning(why)

        # Return missed parameter error.
        return api_response(
            http_code=res.ERROR_999['http_code'],
            message=res.ERROR_999['message'],
            code=res.ERROR_999['code']
        )


    product = add_product(
        brand=brand,
        description=description,
        price=price,
        specification=specification
    )

    # Check if product is already existed.
    if product is None:
        return api_response(
            http_code=res.ERROR_409['http_code'],
            message=res.ERROR_409['message'],
            code=res.ERROR_409['code']
        )

    # Products schema for some fields.
    product_schema = ProductsSchemas(
        only=(
            'id',
            'brand',
            'price',
            'date_added',
            'specification'
        ))

    result = product_schema.dump(product).data

    return api_response(
        http_code=res.PRODUCT_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY['http_code'],
        message=res.PRODUCT_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY['message'],
        payload=result
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type of `specification` get from client request is `str`. When invoking `add_product` function, a `Product` object will be created with `specification` in `str` type.

However according to your `Product` model, `specification` is a foreign key, which should be an object of `Specification`.

**Solutions**:

1. Fix `add_product` function, table `Specification` and `Product` are many-to-many relationships. SQL databases create a third table to achieve many-to-many relationships, just like your `product_specification`.

   So create or get a `Specification` object, create a `Product` object, finally add relationship. Here's an example, just for reference:

   ```
   def add_product(brand=None, description=None, price=None, specification=None):
       spec = Specification(name=specification)
       product = Product(brand=brand, description=description, price=price, specification=spec)
       product.specification.append(spec)
       db.session.add_all([spec, product])
       db.session.commit()
   ```
2. Ajust your models, change the foreign key field to string field. It gonna conflict with project logic, and doesn't solve the problem basicly.

Comment: Thanks @aishenghuomeidaoli 

It helped me a lot and understood how they work.